# Make element inside element with position sticky above other sticky elements

Tags: html, css

In the example below:

```css
.item {
  width: 100%;
}

.item-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
}

.title {
  order: 2;
}

.item-header-right {
  order: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.item-header-right-placeholder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-header">
    <div class="title">hello</div>
    <div class="item-header-right">hello</div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="item-header">
    <div class="title">hello</div>
    <div class="item-header-right-placeholder"></div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="item-header">
    <div class="title">hello</div>
    <div class="item-header-right-placeholder"></div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="item-header">
    <div class="title">hello</div>
    <div class="item-header-right-placeholder"></div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="item-header">
    <div class="title">hello</div>
    <div class="item-header-right-placeholder"></div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

I would like to make it so the top right 'hello' always stays above the other sticky elements when going over them. Is this possible?

Here's the jsfiddle if its easier to edit there:

https://jsfiddle.net/azyfcn7m/

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `position: fixed` on one element and `sticky` on the rest.

Comment: You should never use `<br>` as a spacer for styling.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your remaining structure but this is one way to do it. You make the item `position: fixed;`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
}

.item-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
}

.title {
  order: 2;
}

.item-header-right {
  order: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.item-header-right-placeholder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: red;
}

.fixed-item {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: .25rem;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-item">hello</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="item-header">
    <div class="title">hello</div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="item-header">
    <div class="title">hello</div>
    <div class="item-header-right-placeholder"></div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="item-header">
    <div class="title">hello</div>
    <div class="item-header-right-placeholder"></div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="item-header">
    <div class="title">hello</div>
    <div class="item-header-right-placeholder"></div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="item-header">
    <div class="title">hello</div>
    <div class="item-header-right-placeholder"></div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues with a `<table>` with sticky `<thead>` row and sticky first column `<td>` clash, use CSS `z-index` property to decide what content should be on top.

```
<style>
.details-table-content{
  max-width: 800px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-height: 800px;
}
.details-table-content table {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
.details-table-content table th, td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}
.details-table-content table thead tr th {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.80);
  color: #ffffff;
}
.details-table-content table thead tr th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0; 
  z-index: 1; /* th content on top of td content */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.details-table-content tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color:#454545;
}
.details-table-content table td:first-child {
  position: sticky;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find two different behavior of sticky elements on scroll.
First one: when next sticky element goes above on previous element.
Second one: when previous sticky element goes up and frees position for next element.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #222;
}
.mainParent {
  height: 90%;
  width: 40%;
  background: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.10);
  color: #ddd;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border:4px solid #ddd;
}
.mainParent{margin:0.5em}
.header {
  position: sticky;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #222;
  text-align: center;
  top:0;
}
.content{text-align:center}
```

```html
<div class="mainParent">
  
  <div>
    <div class="header">Header 01</div>
    <div> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum 
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div class="header">Header 02</div>
    <div> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div class="header">Header 03</div>
    <div> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum 
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div class="header">Header 04</div>
    <div> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum 
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div class="header">Header 05</div>
    <div> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum 
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div class="header">Header 06</div>
    <div> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum 
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="mainParent">
  
    <div class="header">Header 01</div>
    <div> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
    </div>
  
    <div class="header">Header 02</div>
    <div> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum 
    </div>
  
    <div class="header">Header 03</div>
    <div> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum 
    </div>
  
    <div class="header">Header 04</div>
    <div> 
      asjkfuia nfasnkj nsajkfn asnfjans jfnaskjn kjfsankj naskjfn kjasnjf nasln asnj nasnf kjnaskjf nkajsnf   jkasnfj naskjfn asjfn kjasnfkj asnfjk naskjfn askjnf kjasnf nasfnk asnf fnaskjfn aksnf 
    </div>
  
    <div class="header">Header 05</div>
    <div> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
    </div>
  
    <div class="header">Header 06</div>
    <div> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum 
    </div>
  
</div>
```